# How to rewrite $\frac{d}{d(x+c)}$?

Tags: derivatives, constants

I would like to know how to rewrite the following equations:

$$
\frac{d (f(x))}{d(x+c)} =0\\
\frac{d^2 (f(x))}{d(x+c)^2} =0\\
$$

Here $x$ is a variable, $c$ is a constant and $f(x)$ is a function of x.
I would also like to know the reasoning behind the answer.

Comment: There is no equality sign so they are not equations anyway.

Comment: why is this getting close votes? If the OP knew how to write a perfect expository paper on Leibniz notation, they presumably wouldn't need to ask the question.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out the answers. When I find one to be the most useful answer to my question, I will mark this question as answered.

Comment: Use $d(x+c)=dx$ and you are done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the chain rule. Define $u = x + c$ then use the fact that $$\frac{d\cdot}{dx} = \frac{du}{dx} \frac{d\cdot}{du}$$ where the $\cdot$ represents any function, so

$$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{du}{dx} \frac{df}{du}$$

It also follows that

$$
\begin{array}{rcll}
\frac{d^2f}{dx^2} &=& \frac{d}{dx} (\frac{df}{dx}) &\quad\mbox{definition of 2nd derivative} \\
&=& \frac{d}{dx} \big(\frac{du}{dx} \frac{df}{du}\big) &\quad\mbox{using the result above} \\
&=& \frac{d}{dx} \big(\frac{du}{dx} \big)\frac{df}{du} + \frac{du}{dx} \frac{d}{dx} \big(\frac{df}{du}\big) &\quad\mbox{using the rule for the derivative of a product} \\
&=& \frac{d^2u}{dx^2} \frac{df}{du} + \frac{du}{dx} \frac{du}{dx} \frac{d}{du} \big(\frac{df}{du}\big) &\quad\mbox{using various results from above} \\
&=& \frac{d^2u}{dx^2} \frac{df}{du} + (\frac{du}{dx})^2 \frac{d^2f}{du^2} &\quad\mbox{simplifying}
\end{array}
$$

So, in summary,

$$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{du}{dx} \frac{df}{du}$$

and

$$\frac{d^2f}{dx^2} = \frac{d^2u}{dx^2} \frac{df}{du} + (\frac{du}{dx})^2 \frac{d^2f}{du^2}$$

The above is correct and valid for *any* $u(x)$ but it's written in a somewhat backwards way. You already have $\frac{df}{dx}$ and $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}$ and want to find $\frac{df}{du}$ and $\frac{d^2f}{du^2}$. Well, that's simple algebra now to get those from the above. It's even simpler with the specific example of $u = x + c$ because, then, $\frac{du}{dx} = 1$ and $\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} = 0$, so

$$\frac{df}{du} = \frac{df}{dx}$$

and

$$\frac{d^2f}{du^2} = \frac{d^2f}{dx^2}$$

for that particular example.

Comment: The problem here is that it is not clear from notation if it is $(x+c)^2$ or the second derivative with respect to $(x+c)$.

Comment: @mathreadler If it were the second derivative one usually writes 
$$\frac{d^{\mathbf{2}}f(x)}{dx^2} $$
though. But you may be correct still.

Comment: Yes Eff, in the case you talk about the derivative is with respect to x, and there can be no confusion from notation. But what was intended in the question was the various derivatives with respect to $(x+c)$ (in some sense).

Comment: @mathreadler If that's the case, then there's a missing superscript 2 in the "numerator", i.e., it should be $\frac{d^2}{d(x+c)^2}$ rather than $\frac{d}{d(x+c)^2}$.

Comment: Yes wltrup you are right, but there were several other things missing in the original formulation also. So the question is, what was intended? It could be many things.

Comment: you guys are right. For the second equation the second derivative was meant, so: $\frac{d^2}{d(x+c)^2}$. What I finally did to find the $\frac{d}{d(x+c)}$ was using the above mentioned chain rule, solving $\frac{d(x+c)}{dx}$ and rewriting to $\frac{d}{d(x+c)} = \frac{dx}{d(x+c)} \cdot \frac{d}{dx}$

Comment: @user3346727 Well, if you meant the second case to be the second derivative, then I need to revise my answer a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Introducing $y=x+c$ one gets
$$
0 
= \frac{d(f(x))}{d(x+c)}
= \frac{d(f(y-c))}{dy}
= f'(y-c) \cdot 1
= f'(x)
= \frac{d(f(x))}{dx}
$$
For the second derivative we get:
$$
0 
= \frac{d^2(f(x))}{d(x+c)^2}
= \frac{d}{d(x+c)} \frac{d(f(x))}{d(x+c)}
= \frac{d(f'(x))}{d(x+c)} = (f')'(x) = f''(x)
= \frac{d^2(f(x))}{dx^2}
$$

Comment: I think in the second case OP is meaning the second derivative (see d^2 on the top)

Comment: Seems like an update. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac { d }{ dx } \left( f\left( x \right) \left( x+c \right) ^{ -1 } \right) =0\\ \frac { df\left( x \right)  }{ dx } \left( x+c \right) ^{ -1 }+f\left( x \right) \frac { d\left( \left( x+c \right) ^{ -1 } \right)  }{ dx } =0\\ \frac { df\left( x \right)  }{ dx } \frac { 1 }{ \left( x+c \right)  } -f\left( x \right) \frac { 1 }{ { \left( x+c \right)  }^{ 2 } } =0$$